# More than one CNAME for S3 website

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cname-record

Is it possible to have more that one CNAME for amazon web services S3 web site?

In docs it is said that bucket name should be equal CNAME.

mysite.com and www.mysite.com as aliaces do I need to create two buckets? It's so strange.

Comment: mysite.com technically can't be a CNAME at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have as many names as you want that target the same CNAME. When they say the bucket name should be the CNAME, they mean the bucket name should be what the CNAME points to. Any number of names can point to the same bucket.

Note that a domain name cannot be a CNAME, only a host name can. So `www.example.com` can be a CNAME to an S3 bucket but `example.com` cannot.

Comment: Thanks, a question if you don't mind: for site to available via http://www.example.com I need to name my bucket as www.example.com, right? What if I want users to reach my site via http://example.com? what should I do?

Comment: The easiest way is to arrange to have your registrar do URL forwarding for you.